# Church numerals and universe inconsistency

Tags: types, coq, type-inference, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

In the following code, the statement `add'_commut` is accepted by Coq but `add_commut` is rejected because of a universe inconsistency.

```
Set Universe Polymorphism.

Definition nat : Type := forall (X : Type), X -> (X -> X) -> X.

Definition succ (n : nat) : nat := fun X z s => s (n X z s).

Definition add' (m n : nat) : nat := fun X z s => m X (n X z s) s.

Definition nat_rec (z : nat) (s : nat -> nat) (n : nat) : nat := n nat z s.
Definition add (m n : nat) : nat := nat_rec n succ m.

Definition equal (A : Type) (a : A) : A -> Type := fun a' => forall (P : A -> Type), P a -> P a'.

Lemma add'_commut (m n : nat) : equal nat (add' m n) (add' n m).
Admitted.

Lemma add_commut (m n : nat) : equal nat (add m n) (add n m).
(*
In environment
m : nat
n : nat
The term "add n (fun X : Type => m X)" has type
 "nat@{Top.1078 Top.1079}"
while it is expected to have type
 "nat@{Top.1080 Top.1078}" (universe inconsistency).
*)
```

How to make it go through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Church numerals only work if you turn on impredicative `Set`, by putting `-arg -impredicative-set` into your `_CoqProject` file or using `-impredicative-set` command line option. Then define `nat` as:

```
Definition nat : Set := forall (X : Set), X -> (X -> X) -> X.
```

Impredicative `Set` allows `nat` to have exactly the same type `Set` which it quantifies over. Without impredicativity, `nat` must have a higher universe level than what it quantifies over, although the levels are hidden from you until you get an error like in the question.

Note that impredicative `Set` is [incompatible](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/The-Logic-of-Coq) with classical logic.

Comment: Shouldn't universe polymorphism be able to deal with this?

Comment: No, without impredicativity, universe levels get raised on basic operations such as addition, preventing simple things like doing addition iteratively.  Universe polymorphism can't work out level constraints which are impossible with respect to predicative Coq.